# What happens when a 64-bit value is passed as a parameter in a function on a 32-bit architecture?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, calling-convention, cortex-m

I am facing a weird issue. I am passing a `uint64_t` offset to a function on a 32-bit architecture(Cortex R52). The registers are all 32-bit.

This is the function. :
Sorry, I messed up the function declaration.

```
void read_func(uint8_t* read_buffer_ptr, uint64_t offset, size_t size);
```

```
main(){
   // read_buffer : memory where something is read.
   // read_buffer_ptr : points to read_buffer structure where value should be stored after reading value.
   read_func(read_buffer_ptr, 0, sizeof(read_buffer));
}
```

In this function, the value stored in `offset` is not zero but some random values which I also see in the registers(`r5, r6`). Also, when I use `offset` as a 32-bit value, it works perfectly fine. The value is copied from r2,r3 into r5,r6.

Can you please let me know why this could be happening? Are registers not enough?

Comment: Check the ARM calling convention docs your compiler is using, and/or look at the asm generated for the C caller.  Should make it clear which args go in regs and how the leftover regs are passed on the stack.

Comment: `void read_func(uint8_t* read_buffer_ptr, uint64_t offset, sizeof(read_buffer)` this function will not compiler. Show ***real*** code not this invalid "something"

Comment: Have you compiled 'read_func' with the same compiler setting? Have you properly declared it?

Comment: please provide input values and the values you are seeing in the debugger once the function is called.

Comment: Generally speaking - assume that the compiler is always right.

Comment: There's not enough code here to see what the problem might be.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is so small that I am just passing a uint64 variable to a function and the value received on the other end is not what was passed. So it becomes difficult to create an example.

Comment: I think we really do need more details, including how you are making these observations.  For instance, in some cases, debuggers may show an incorrect value for a variable or argument at certain points in the program, even if the code is perfectly correct.  The debug info might state that the variable is in a particular register or memory location, but you may have a breakpoint at a point in the code where that location has not yet been initialized.

Comment: Yes. I thought so. Although I am checking the arguments at the start of function, these same values get passed to another function. When I am passing these values to another function, then these values should be what I had passed. IN this case, it should be zero. But that does not happen. It gives me a different value but every time, the value is same. And a combination of r2,r3.

Comment: I am also checking the values before passing it to another function just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype posted is invalid, it should be:

```
void read_func(uint8_t *read_buffer_ptr, uint64_t offset, size_t size);
```

Similarly, the definition `main()` is obsolete: the implicit `int` return type is not supported as of c99, the function call has another syntax error with a missing `)`...

What happens when you pass a 64-bit argument on a 32-bit architecture is implementation defined:

- either 8 bytes of stack space are used to pass the value
- or 2 32-bit registers are used to pass the least significant part and the most significant part
- or a combination of both depending on the number of arguments
- or some other scheme appropriate for the target CPU

In your code you pass `0` which has type `int` and presumably has only 32 bits. This is not a problem if the prototype for `read_func` was correct and parsed before the function call, otherwise the behavior is undefined and a C99 compiler should not even compile the code, but may compilers will just issue a warning and generate bogus code.

In your case (Cortex R52), the 64-bit argument is passed to `read_func` in registers r2 and r3.

Comment: The prototype is same as what you have written actually. Maybe I should pass uint64_t(0)?

Comment: @omkarkale The prototype is only the same now because you edited the post!

Comment: Yes. And I also mentioned that "Sorry, I messed up the function declaration."I was in a hurry. That's why I made the mistake. If I had used the function declaration that I had previously posted, it wont have compiled.

Comment: Somewhere in the calling convention manual it's written that 64bit values are stored starting from an even register index. So in function call they can be put in r0-r1 or r2-r3. That's probably because ldrd and strd (at least in the cortex-m architecture) works the same way, the can be used only with a couple of registers that must be close to each other and starting with even index.

Comment: No i'm wrong on the cortex-m part. Double can be loaded/stored in two gp registers without any limitations. (It seams)

Answer (score -2):

1. Cortex-R52 has 32 bits address bus and offset cannot be 64 bits. In calculations only lower 32bits will be used as higher ones will not have any effect.

example:

```
uint64_t foo(void *buff, uint64_t offset, uint64_t size)
{
    unsigned char *cbuff = buff;
    
    while(size--)
    {
        *(cbuff++ + offset) = size & 0xff;
    }
    return offset + (uint32_t)cbuff;
}

void *z1(void);
uint64_t z2(void);
uint64_t z3(void);

uint64_t bar(void)
{
    return foo(z1(), z2(), z3());
}
```

```
foo:
        push    {r4, lr}
        ldr     lr, [sp, #8]    //size
        ldr     r1, [sp, #12]   //size
        mov     ip, lr
        add     r4, r0, r2     // cbuff + offset calculation r3 is ignored as not needed - processor has only 32bits address space.
.L2:
        subs    ip, ip, #1     //size--
        sbc     r1, r1, #0     //size--
        cmn     r1, #1
        cmneq   ip, #1
        bne     .L3
        add     r0, r0, lr
        adds    r0, r0, r2
        adc     r1, r3, #0
        pop     {r4, pc}
.L3:
        strb    ip, [r4], #1
        b       .L2
bar:
        push    {r0, r1, r4, r5, r6, lr}
        bl      z1
        mov     r4, r0      // buff
        bl      z2
        mov     r6, r0      // offset
        mov     r5, r1      // offset
        bl      z3
        mov     r2, r6      // offset
        strd    r0, [sp]    // size passed on the stack
        mov     r3, r5      // offset
        mov     r0, r4      // buff
        bl      foo
        add     sp, sp, #8
        pop     {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

As you see resister r2 & r3 contain the offset, r0 - buff and size is on the stack.

Comment: Where does the question say `offset` is a memory offset and not a file offset or some other type of offset?

Comment: @EricPostpischil no difference. It is passed in R2 & R3 registers not R5, R6 as OP thinks.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the question and should not be in the answer. That the argument is passed in r2 and r3 should be the first sentence in the answer, not the last.

Comment: Yes, it is a memory operation. And the offset is a fie offset.

Comment: And yes, it is passed in R2 and R3. And not in R5, R6. It is actually copied there in the assembly code.

Comment: Interesting why people hate so much this answer

Comment: I will also take this into consideration.